# dynamic (number of entire rows) insert copied cells macro

Tags: excel, range, rows, vba

I have the following macro made by someone else :

---

```
Sub test2()
Dim n As Integer, rng As Range
'n = InputBox("type the value of n")
Set rng = Range("a1")
rng.Select
line2:
n = InputBox("type no. of times you want to be repeated minus 1 for e.g if you wnat to be repeated 3 times type 2")
Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(n, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)).Copy
Range(rng, rng.Offset(n, 0)).PasteSpecial
Set rng = rng.Offset(n + 1, 0)
If rng = "" Then
GoTo line1
Else
GoTo line2
End If
line1:
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("a1").Select
MsgBox "macro over"
Stop


End Sub
```

---

1. I want the range selection to be dynamic i.e  in the above code its hard coded to "a1" but since i want to repeat the macro again and again i want to select different starting point every time by selecting it through my mouse click.
2. Also when i am done with copying the cells its restarts, and i want to stop the macro once i have copied it one time . then select the new starting point select a row and then copy it x # of times

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you presented has some strange logic. Trying to change it according to your needs I changed a bit more then you asked for. I hope this is what you need, now. See some comments inside the sub, too.

```
Sub test2()
Dim n As Integer, rng As Range

    'new section >>
    On Error GoTo EH
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select any cell/cells within range to copy", Type:=8)
    '<<---

rng.Select

line2:
n = InputBox("type no. of times you want to be repeated minus 1 for e.g if you wnat to be repeated 3 times type 2")
Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(n, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)).Copy
Range(rng, rng.Offset(n, 0)).PasteSpecial

'Selection code:
Rng.offset(n,0).select

    'this section is not necessary>>
    'Set rng = rng.Offset(n + 1, 0)
    'If rng = "" Then
    'GoTo line1
    'Else
    'GoTo line2
    'End If

line1:
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'range("a1").Select 'i don't think you need it
MsgBox "macro over"

    'Stop is not neede

Exit Sub
EH:
    MsgBox "Sub interrupted"

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok How can i actually select the last row of the copied cells .likei copied a secific row 30 times then after macro is completed i want the selection to highlight the 30th row

Comment: Removing answer approval makes me less willing to help you more.It works just the opposit to what you expect.

Comment: Hmmm had no intention to do it that way... just wanted to get hold of you. D

Comment: As i am new to this i tried going to ur rofile and messaging you and coudnt.  So can you please help me out.